# Develope Sharepoint solution in VS2010 in Development machine and sharepoint 2013 in Server machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

Am very new to Sharepoint , i installed the VS2010 in development machine and Sharepoint 2013 installed in Server machine. now i have to Develope Sharepoint solution in VS2010.

but in sharepoint wizard,

> it asking the site and security for debugging :i have given the my site in textbox which running in my local machine. and when i validated that,
> am getting the

```
SharePoint Connection Error
---------------------------
```

> Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: my site. Make sure that the Site URL is valid, that the SharePoint site is running on the local computer, and that the current user has the necessary permissions to access the site.
>
> Additional information:
>
> A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer. A SharePoint server must be installed to work with SharePoint projects.

**Am one of the active directory user
**I have the privileged to access my site what i created in Central admin
**VS 2010 installed in Development machine, sahrepoint 2013 installed in server machine, am using the  sahrepoint , by sharepoint dll installed into GAC in to develpment machine.

any one come across this problem and know the solution for it. ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says:

> Make sure that the Site URL is valid, that the SharePoint site is **running on the local computer**

You need to install SP2013 on your dev enviroment.

Comment: my sharepoint site is correct that i was checked.. and is this necessary to install sp2013 on dev machine. ? is there any option to create sharepoint solution without sp2013 in deve machine?

Comment: Yes it is.
Please set as accepted answer if I helped you.

Comment: hi greg,i have tried to create the webpart using WebApplication as usual how we create web application in ASP.NET. and also delployed in sever manually. but now am trying to develop even handler ... is there  any option to create event handler in ASP.NET without Sharepoint Solution. ?

Comment: and also one more question Mr.Greg, if we need to install sP2013 in Dev machine, then how it is possible to install sp2013 in all dev machine, surely more than 2 or 3 developer in sharepoint,if we install sp2013 in all dev machine, how it is worth, then what is the use of server having sp2013?.

Comment: Basically if you want to create SharePoint solutions you need dev enviroment with SP2013 server installed (every developer should have he's own enviroment). Only exception is when you build SharePoint 2013 Apps then you don't need SP2013 installed on your dev enviroment.

Comment: You should use a separated SP2013 server for test and staging. It is highly recommended to test SP solutions on a dedicated server (not dev).

Comment: k thanks for clarified my doubts. but still i have question about tat , is there option to create EventHandler in ASP.NET application?.. and  also one more clarification please dont mistake me, am new to sharepoint, thats y am asking you,  if we try to create eventhandler on development machine without sharepoint installation, can we get the SharePoint Connection Error that what i mentioned above in this post?

Comment: What kind of project did you create? If you created 'Empty SharePoint Project' (or any SP project) then if you don't have SP installed you always get the connection error. What kind of event handler do you plan to create?

Comment: ,i have created the simple addition calculation in usercontrol in ASP.NET Web application and also deployed it in sever and then got the my web part in sharepoint. this i was tried without installation of sharepoint on development machince, but i  was referred  Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll. i want to try the BeforeEvent in list.

Comment: To Develope sharepoint solution on Dev machince:                                should i install the SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK?
see the below link.
    http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585        is this enough to develope sharepoint solution on dev machine?         or anyother plugins i should install in to Dev machine.?